# Virtual Box Guest Additions Install - Linux (CentOS - Ubuntu)

Tags: ubuntu, centos, virtualbox

how to check whether Virtualbox Guest Additions have been installed on CentOS or any linux distro for that matter ?

I have a few Linux based VMs in Virtualbox and have forgotten whether I had installed Guest additions or not :-)

Would be grateful.
Kind Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ps -A

Look for instances of "VBoxClient" (may be a few).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way I can sort the output of that command alphabetically ? I have tried `ps -A | grep "VB"` - still learning the command line :-) - thanks again !

Comment: ps -A | grep "VBoxService" - should bring it down to a single "hit."